# The same object is not always the same?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, comparison, object-equality

Why `b` [is not equal](https://jsfiddle.net/vtkmm1ur/1/) to `null` at the end of the following code?

```
var a = { property: "value" }, 
    b = a;
console.log(a === b); // true

a = null;
console.log(b); // Object { property: "value" }
```

I thought that `a` and `b` are two references tied to one object and therefore will both became `null`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language

Comment: @BirjuShah: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/4554883

Comment: which is true, but why are you expecting b to be null. I mean how do you relate it with the comment

Comment: By the comment I'm telling you that `always pass-by-value` is not true, and your comment does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line:

```
a = 5;
```

You're pointing 'a' to a new block of memory containing an integer of value 5, overwriting it's previous reference to the object you originally created. Try this instead:

```
var a = { property: "value" }, 
b = a;
console.log(a === b); // true

a.property = 5;
console.log(b); // Object {property: 5}
```

This way you're not overwriting `a`, but rather changing the block of memory the key `property` points to from a string with value `"value"`, to an integer with value `5`.

This preserves `a`'s reference to the block of memory containing the object you originally created, which you also set 'b' to point to in the next line.

Edit: The above was to answer your previous question. If you set `a` to null, it simply deletes it's reference to the original object. The object won't be garbage collected while anything (`b` in this case) still has a reference to it. After you create `b`, the references are independent, but both happen to point to the same block of memory.

Comment: Did you mean `a.property = 5`?

Comment: Oops, my bad, copy and pasted the wrong part from the jsfiddle.